# How to convert a pandas dataframe to a docstring layout

Tags: python, pandas

consider following dataframe:

```
{('CA', 'ca'): {('A', 'a'): 2,
 ('A', 'aa'): 2,
  ('B', 'b'): 2,
  ('B', 'bb'): 2,
  ('C', 'c'): 2,
  ('C', 'cc'): 2},
 ('CA', 'cb'): {('A', 'a'): 1,
  ('A', 'aa'): 1,
  ('B', 'b'): 1,
  ('B', 'bb'): 1,
  ('C', 'c'): 1,
  ('C', 'cc'): 1}}
```

How can I convert the dataframe to a layout which can be inserted into the doctstrings by copy and paste similar to this one?

```
+-------------+----------+---------+
| First       |   Second |   Third |
+=============+==========+=========+
| ('A', 'a')  |        2 |       1 |
+-------------+----------+---------+
...
```

Comment: Explain the logic of the transformation, where does the `v` come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`tabulate`](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) might get you started:

```
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        ("CA", "ca"): {
            ("A", "a"): 2,
            ("A", "aa"): 2,
            ("B", "b"): 2,
            ("B", "bb"): 2,
            ("C", "c"): 2,
            ("C", "cc"): 2,
        },
        ("CA", "cb"): {
            ("A", "a"): 1,
            ("A", "aa"): 1,
            ("B", "b"): 1,
            ("B", "bb"): 1,
            ("C", "c"): 1,
            ("C", "cc"): 1,
        },
    }
)

tab = tabulate(df, tablefmt="grid")
print(tab)
```

which outputs

```
+-------------+---+---+
| ('A', 'a')  | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
| ('A', 'aa') | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
| ('B', 'b')  | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
| ('B', 'bb') | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
| ('C', 'c')  | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
| ('C', 'cc') | 2 | 1 |
+-------------+---+---+
```

you can also add `headers`:

```
headers = ["First", "Second", "Third"]
tab = tabulate(df, headers=headers, tablefmt="grid")
```

which will then generate

```
+-------------+----------+---------+
| First       |   Second |   Third |
+=============+==========+=========+
| ('A', 'a')  |        2 |       1 |
+-------------+----------+---------+
...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for forgiving my bad layout of the question. I adapted it. You saved me and others a ton of work. Have a nice day

Comment: @Moritz oh, very kind of you. thanks! & grüsse nach wien!